# populate dropdown in codeigniter form using set_value

Tags: codeigniter, drop-down-menu, validation, setvalue

i have a form that uses a drop down and im using codeigniter , form helper and form validation
so when i get a validation error in my form , all the correctly entered fields are populated using set_value of codeigniter , however this doesnt work for dropdown

im doing :

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('mid', $id_map, set_value('mid'), 'id="mid"') ?>
```

when get error in form , always the first value of dropdown is selected and not previously set

Any ideas , what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The correct method to use `set_select()` is

```
<select name="myselect">
<option value="one" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'one', TRUE); ?> >One</option>
<option value="two" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'two'); ?> >Two</option>
<option value="three" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'three'); ?> >Three</option>
</select>
```

So Andras Ratz method/answer won't work.

Your method is correct.

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('mid', $id_map, set_value('mid'), 'id="mid"') ?>
```

However remember that `set_value()` is only going to return the value if you have setup a validation rule for it, in your case for `mid`.  You could try as below -

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('mid', $id_map, (isset($_POST['mid']) ? $_POST['mid'] : ''), 'id="mid"') ?>
```

or just set a validation rule for `mid` too

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have to use the set_select() function , not the set_value();

You can check that here:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

And the right syntax:

**EDIT :**

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('mid', $id_map,  set_select('mid'), 'id="mid"'); ?>
```

If you have a default value, that should go in the 2. parameter for set_select.

I hope this will work.

Comment: @AndrásRátz your method "`echo form_dropdown('mid', $id_map,  set_select('mid'), 'id="mid"');`"  is wrong mate - see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php // Change the values in this array to populate your dropdown as required
                    $options = array(
                    'active' => 'Active',
                    'inactive' => 'Inactive',
                    );
                    echo form_dropdown('mid', $options,$id_map, ' id="mid"');
                    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about if the the form select content is selected from a foreach loop like this

```
<?php foreach ($roles as $role) {
        echo "<option value=" . $role->id . ">" . $role->role_name . "</option>";
                      }
      ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you do not have a validation rule on the actual dropdown field, then

```
echo form_dropdown('mid',$id_map);
```

is sufficient.

Comment: I don't know what the down vote is for. This code worked for me yesterday in making a form field "sticky" after the other methods failed.