# I have trouble in set_select in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have worked in a codeigniter framework and i have a problem in select tag.
when i want to achieve the value of option that i have selected.
i used the method as when i select the option value then i pressed the search button and after what i need the result its showing and then i want to again the value of the selected option with second submit button and the whole data with selected option value must be go to data base. the code is as follow.

```
<select id="faculty" data-rel="chosen" name='stdid'>
<option>select student</option>
<?php   
foreach ($student as $s) {
echo '<option set_select("student","'.$s['stdid'].'","true") value="'.$s['stdid'].'">'.$s['stdname'].' '  .$s['stdid'].'</option>';
}?> 
</select>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [populate dropdown in codeigniter form using set\_value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986786/populate-dropdown-in-codeigniter-form-using-set-value)

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing PHP with HTML. Change the code to this:

```
<select id="faculty" data-rel="chosen" name="stdid">
<option>select student</option>
<?php   
foreach ($student as $s) {
    echo '<option'.set_select("stdid", $s['stdid'], true).' value="'.$s['stdid'].'">'.$s['stdname'].' '.$s['stdid'].'</option>';
}?> 
</select>
```

Note that setting all the `option` elements to `set_select("stdid", $s['stdid'], true)` will become `selected="selected"`. Read more about [set_select](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html).