# Keep values of dropdown list after failed form verification CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following dropdown list:

```
<select name="technology" class="form-control">
<option value=""></option>
<?php
foreach ($technology as $each) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?=$each['technology']?>"><?=$each['technology']?></option>
    <?php
}
?>
</select>
```

The list is populated from a DB. I am using Codeigniter framework. I have tried the following to keep the values, after form submission, but it does not work:

```
<select name="category" class="form-control">
<option value=""></option>
<?php
foreach ($category as $each) {
    ?>

    <option value="<?=$each['category']?>"<?php echo set_select('category', '$each["category"]'); ?> ><?=$each['category']?></option>
    <?php
}
?>
</select>
```

There are a couple of dropdowns on the page I am populating from the Database. 
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about some correction in the syntax:

```
<select name="category" class="form-control">
<option value=""></option>
<?php
foreach ($category as $each) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $each['category']; ?>"<?php echo set_select('category', $each["category"]); ?> ><?php echo $each['category']; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Please try the edited answer :) 
I guess that the issue with the  single quotations you added to the PHP variables inside set_select dude

Comment: Yeah I saw that :) I will try it too
EDIT: Yes, this works too. And it is closer to the answer I was looking for. I will mark this as the correct answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I think so

Comment: When using a framework try to use the inbuilt functions available. In CI there is a form helper with handy functions for form building. You can use form_dropdown() to create a dropdown list in your form.
More form helper functions can be found here: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am using the helpers for the other fields, but because I am new to CI, I prefer to use HTML select fields to populate my dropdowns from DB, as I find it easier. All the other fields (form_open, form_close, form_upload and form_input) are in use for this form. Also, the examples to keep the values of the dropdown fields in the CI documentation are showing an example that is not using the helpers for some reason. I was following that. see this link: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#set_select

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986786/populate-dropdown-in-codeigniter-form-using-set-value

I hope you will find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like that:

**Example for technology field:**

```
<option <?=((isset($_POST['technology']) && $_POST['technology'] == $each['technology']) ? 
    'selected=""' : '')?> 
    value="<?=$each['technology']?>"><?=$each['technology']?></option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code if you return array using result_array() in model;

    <select name="category" class="form-control">
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php
    foreach ($category as $each) {
        ?>

        <option value="<?=$each['category']?>"<?php echo set_select('category', '$each["category"]'); ?> ><?=$each['category']?></option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select>


Use this code if you return array using result() in model;

    <select name="category" class="form-control">
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php
    foreach ($category as $each) {
        ?>

        <option value="<?=$each->category?>"<?php echo set_select('category', '$each->category'); ?> ><?=$each->category?></option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the most easy way

model.php

$this->db->where('item', $value);
return $this->db->get('table')->result();

view.php

$value):?>
        " ' : ''?>>